# PHP/MySQL critical error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a game and users can buy things on the market etc, but if i'm using 2 computers and click at the exact same time my money will be duplicated. How can I lock the row and make the second request fail?

```
$db = getDB();  
$sql = "UPDATE users SET money = money- :money WHERE username=:user";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':money', $amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->execute();
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have your app been accessed only from 1 instance for given username

Comment: do not ask the same question twice. edit your other question to add more clarification. At the moment your question makes noi sense

Comment: Attempting to "lock the row" in the database seems like the wrong approach to solving the problem.

Sounds like we want to disallow the same `username` from posting identical (or similar) requests "at the same time" from multiple sessions (computers).

I would address that issue earlier in the code than the database update.